# C++ Compilando/Incluindo todos arquivos .cpp dos subdiretórios da pasta /src

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, makefile, mingw, c++17

Utilizo o Visual Studio Code + MinGW.

Meu projeto é o https://github.com/KaueAlves/Grimorie-Tabuleiro

Como algumas IDES fazem o link entre as classes automaticamente, ao usar o VSCODE me deparei com a necessidade de passar os parâmetros da compilação.

Como eu faço para ler todos os arquivos `.cpp` de todos os diretórios em `/src` e depois gerar o aquivo `.exe`?

O meu markfile está atualmente assim, entretando ele funciona apenas nos níveis que eu adcionar ao `FOLDERS` :

```
#LIBARIES := 
#INCLUDES :=
FOLDERS  := src/*.cpp src/*/*.cpp
FILES    := main.cpp
all:
    g++ -g  -std=c++17  -Wall   $(INCLUDES) $(FOLDERS)  $(FILES)    -o  main
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode utilizar [wildcards](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Wildcard-Function.html) para isso.  Ficaria algo assim (não testei):

```
src = $(wildcard *.cpp) \
      $(wildcard src/*.cpp) \
      $(wildcard src/pecas/*.cpp)
obj = $(src:.cpp=.o)

CXXFLAGS= -O2 -std=c++17 -Wall

game: $(obj) 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $@ $^

.PHONY: clean
clean: 
    rm -f $(obj) game
```

No mais, recomendo seriamente que você passe a utilizar CMake para os seus projetos. 
A sintaxe é mais intuitiva que GNU Make.